# Jordan canonical form of a square matrix with rational entries

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $$A\in M_n(\mathbb{Q})$$ and $B$ it's Jordan canonical form. Is it true that B must have only rational entries? What if $A\in M_n(\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: What about e.g. $\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}$?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. As an example, the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{1 & 1\\1 & 0}
$$
has the Jordan form
$$
B = \frac 12\pmatrix{1 + \sqrt{5} & 0\\ 0 & 1 - \sqrt{5}}.
$$
It is true, however, that if $A$ is rational, then the [Frobenius normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form) of $A$ will have rational entries.

Comment: Hello, I have been following your answers & you seem to be an expert on Linear algebra, I really admire your skills,can you recommend me some practice books  on the subject ? I am using Axler as a textbook.

Comment: @night_crawler That's quite the compliment, thank you. Axler is great, I'd also recommend Friedberg Insel and Spence. A lot of my exposure to linear algebra came from a class I took in grad school based on *Matrix Analysis* by Horn and Johnson and from classes I took related to functional analysis (essentially linear algebra with a focus on infinite dimensional spaces). Actually, Axler's text is very much geared towards the functional analysis perspective

Comment: @night_crawler I should also mention that abstract algebra also informs my perspective on linear algebra and that Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis* is another excellent text. With all that said, I ascribe most of my particular set of strengths and weaknesses not to the particular books I read but to my approach to learning. Primarily, I am motivated by interesting questions and I try to fill in what I'm missing until I get those answers, at least to the extent that my attention span allows. Most of what I learned I picked up while trying to answer a math problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was some wonderful  advice . I will try to follow it, thanks again.